# SELECT INTO dynamic temp table using procedure with dynamic parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't find a full solution to my problem. I have an existing stored procedure that takes dynamic input as a parameter value. I need to execute this procedure (with a dynamic variable) and would like to somehow SELECT * INTO #mytable without having to declare the schema of the temp table.

I've tried using OPENROWSET but it doesn't allow me to specify the variable (only hard-code it):

```
select * into #table from openrowset('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'exec SERVER..MYSTOREDPROCEDURE @parameter = 123')
```

The only other way I'm aware of is wrapping it in a string and using EXEC(@sql), but I can't figure out how to "SELECT * INTO #table" from that.

What are my options? Can I create a UDF table function that can return a dynamic table? Doubtful...

Comment: I don't really see what the problem is here? If you `CREATE` a temporary table and execute dynamic SQL **in the same connection** you can reference it. For example: `CREATE TABLE #test (ID int);

EXEC sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO #test VALUES (1);';

SELECT *
FROM #test;

DROP TABLE #test;`

Comment: @Larnu I think I found it, he doesn't want to declare the schema of the temp table.

Comment: And how's the rest of your code intending to use this table with an unknown schema, if you were capable of creating it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but you'll need to do the whole thing in dynamic SQL. So, instead, something like:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @param nvarchar(10) = 123;
SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'INTO #table' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;'', ''exec SERVER..MYSTOREDPROCEDURE @parameter = ' + QUOTENAME(@param,N'''') +N''');' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(10) + --Of course, I assume you're doing something more complex that a SELECT *.
           N'FROM #table;';
PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: This is what I was looking at, but how do I access #table from outside the exec statement? Is the #table not created in tempdb? I can't seem to access #table after I have executed the first statement to insert into it.

Comment: @RyanPeters You can't access a temporary table created inside dynamic SQL outside of the dynamic SQL, however, the opposite is true (as shown in my original comment).

Comment: As a result, you might better off doing `INTO tempdb..[table]` and then using `DROP TABLE tempdb..[table];` at the end of your batch.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I really only had to modify the temp variable names to put the temp table into the global scope. This works for me with my actual tables (I renamed them for the purposes of this post).

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##mytemptable') is not null drop table ##mytemptable

declare @id int = 112

declare @sql nvarchar(max) ='SELECT * INTO ##mytemptable FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;'', ''exec SERVER..MyStoredProcedure @ID =' + convert(varchar(10), id) + ''')'

-- invokes and inserts into ##mytemptable
exec sp_executesql @sql

-- now I can query from the global scope
select * from ##mytemptable
```

Comment: You know that you have to be careful. In case that code runs from different connections against different sources/procedure your results might be unpredictable.

Comment: Right. Thankfully this will be a once-per-day process.

Comment: Then why you wouldn't use a staging table or series of them: one for each procedure? That would be faster than creating temp tables and be visible only in scope of that DB.